# CSS Layout Improvements

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout and I would like to know the following:

- When I have more data how can I make the gray background repeat down the page more?
- With my portfolio I have `margin-left:25px` the wrapper but how can I make sure it stops at the end of the content background?

CSS:

```
html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:url(../img/bg.jpg) repeat;
}
body{
    width:960px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#e3e3e3;
    margin:42px auto;
}
p,h1,h2{
    margin:25px;
}
h1{
    color:#67686a;
    font:18px Myriad Pro bold;
}
p{
    font:Myriad Pro;
    color:#99999a;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#99999a;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#space{
    padding:10px 0 0 0;
}
header{
    width:100%;
    height:160px;
}
#logo{
    height:100px;
    width:159px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat;
}

header nav{
    width:410px;
    height:18px;
    margin:3px auto;
}
header nav ul{
    width:100%;
    height:18px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
header nav ul li{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
header nav li a{
    float:left;
    width:85px;
    padding:0 3px 3px 3px;
    font:18px Myriad Pro;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color:#99999a;
}
header nav li a:hover, a:active, .current{
    font:18px Myriad Pro bold;
    color:#67686a;
}
header nav .first{
    margin:0 0 0 25px;
}
#line{
    clear:both;
    width:610px;
    height:1px;
    margin:0 0 0 235px;
    background:url('../img/line.png') no-repeat;
}
#banner{
    width:100%;
    height:161px;
}
#content{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#e3e3e3;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
footer{
    width:150;
    height:24px;
}
footer p{
    color:#e3e3e3;
}

/*Portfolio*/

#portfolioWrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 0 0 25px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
#portfolioBox{
    float:left;
    padding-left:8px;
}
#portfolioBox img{
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:green;
}
#portfolioBox p{
    width:150px;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        {pyro:theme:partial name="metadata"}
</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="space"></div>
            <div id="logo"></div>
                <div id="line"></div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        {pyro:navigation:links group="header" indent="tab"} 
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="banner" class="nivoSlider">
            {pyro:galleries:images slug="template-slider" limit="5"}
            <img src="{pyro:url:base}uploads/default/files/{name}" alt="{description}">
            {/pyro:galleries:images}
        </section>
            <section id="content">
                {if ('{pyro:page:is_portfolio}' == TRUE)}

                {else}
                <h1>{pyro:page:title}</h1>
                {/if}
                <p>
                {pyro:page:body}
                </p>

                    <div id="portfolioWrapper">
                        <div id="portfolioBox">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="">
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a vestibulum nisi. Ut ligula nulla, ullamcorper quis tempor nec, ultrices a         tortor. Integer tellus tellus, dignissim vel volutpat vitae, viverra vitae mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce massa mi, tincidunt eu malesuada sit amet, elementum eu mi.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div id="portfolioBox">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="">
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a vestibulum nisi. Ut ligula nulla, ullamcorper quis tempor nec, ultrices a tortor. Integer tellus tellus, dignissim vel volutpat vitae, viverra vitae mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce massa mi, tincidunt eu malesuada sit amet, elementum eu mi.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div id="portfolioBox">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="">
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a vestibulum nisi. Ut ligula nulla, ullamcorper quis tempor nec, ultrices a tortor. Integer tellus tellus, dignissim vel volutpat vitae, viverra vitae mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce massa mi, tincidunt eu malesuada sit amet, elementum eu mi.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div id="portfolioBox">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="">
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a vestibulum nisi. Ut ligula nulla, ullamcorper quis tempor nec, ultrices a tortor. Integer tellus tellus, dignissim vel volutpat vitae, viverra vitae mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce massa mi, tincidunt eu malesuada sit amet, elementum eu mi.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div id="portfolioBox">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="">
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a vestibulum nisi. Ut ligula nulla, ullamcorper quis tempor nec, ultrices a tortor. Integer tellus tellus, dignissim vel volutpat vitae, viverra vitae mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce massa mi, tincidunt eu malesuada sit amet, elementum eu mi.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div id="portfolioBox">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="">
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a vestibulum nisi. Ut ligula nulla, ullamcorper quis tempor nec, ultrices a tortor. Integer tellus tellus, dignissim vel volutpat vitae, viverra vitae mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce massa mi, tincidunt eu malesuada sit amet, elementum eu mi.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div id="portfolioBox">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" alt="">
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a vestibulum nisi. Ut ligula nulla, ullamcorper quis tempor nec, ultrices a tortor. Integer tellus tellus, dignissim vel volutpat vitae, viverra vitae mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce massa mi, tincidunt eu malesuada sit amet, elementum eu mi.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                    </div>      
    </section>
        <footer>
                <p>&copy; {pyro:settings:site_name} | {pyro:helper:date format="Y"}
            </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body{
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    background-color:#e3e3e3;
    margin:42px auto;
}
```

the height: auto; will resize the content depending how dig is the div inside, and min-height will keep body's height not less then 100%

http://jsfiddle.net/bxZC2/1/

**update**

```
#content{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#e3e3e3;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried this but its not repeating http://develop.jzm.co.nz/pyrocms/portfolio

Comment: based on your posted code it's working. I geve you the example of it in jsfiddle. I downloaded your site now, I'll see what I can do, will be back in a few minutes with an answer.